# React useState, setState in useEffect not updating array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I've seen this problem on SO, but I cannot seem to work out why it exists.

I am following the tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-simple-real-time-chat-with-net-core-reactjs-and-signalr-6367dcadd2c6)

I am using useState but when I try to update the state, the array is empty. I am using state to create initially an empty array. on message received, I am trying to add the message to the array, using the spread operator, which I have used countless times to add an object to an array (but never inside useEffect).

If I uncomment the commented lines, "chat" gets updated as it should do, but I cannot understand why the spread operator is not working and I need to use a useRef to make this work. I don't want to have loads of useRef for every corresponding useState (at least not knowing why it is necessary)

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, or explain why I need the useRef?

```
const [chat, setChat ] = useState([]);

//const latestChat = useRef(null);
//latestChat.current = chat;

// ...

useEffect(() => {
    if (connection) {
        connection.start()
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Connected!');

                connection.on('ReceiveMessage', message => {
                    const newMsg = {
                        user: message.user,
                        message:message.message
                    }
                    setChat([...chat, newMsg]); // issue with this line. chat is always empty

                    //const updatedChat = [...latestChat.current];
                    //updatedChat.push(message);
                    //setChat(updatedChat);
                    
                    
                });
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('Connection failed: ', e));
    }
}, [connection]);
```

Comment: You should use `setChat(chat => [...chat, newMsg])` instead of `setChat([...chat, newMsg])`

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @TaghiKhavari - I tried the first way before posting but it didn't work for me. I'm going to try the second way shortly, but still confused why my code doesnt work in useEffect but does in a regular function but thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have two option here

1. add `chat` state to `useEffect dependency array` so it knows it depends on `chat`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (connection) {
    //...
    setChat([...chat, newMsg]); // issue with this line. chat is always empty
    //...
  }
}, [connection, chat]);
```

2. use `setState callback` to update `chat` so you won't get `stale data`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (connection) {
    //...
    setChat((ch) => [...ch, newMsg]); // issue with this line. chat is always empty
    //...
  }
}, [connection]);
```

which the second way is more appropriate.

Comment: A million thanks. The second option works perfectly. Googling your key words right now to learn more. Thanks for highlighting them.

Comment: @grayson glad I could help, Cheers