# React State updating component, but not State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

Updated 17/01/2021

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65719838/3482632) and got a perfect answer from @TaghiKhavari, which I am using and works well to add an item to an array and removes the stale state issue.

However, I am having a further issue with what I thought was a race condition, but I am not sure now having done further debugging and not sure how to fix it. I have tried moving from a class based model which I am using to a simple array of objects, but that makes no different.

Here is my code inside a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (connection) {
        connection.start()
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Connected!');
                ...

                connection.on('ConnectedToRoom', (id, name) => {
                    const newPerson = new PersonModel ({
                        id: sid,
                        firstName: name,
                        present: true
                    })
                    
                    const pd = people.models
                    pd.push(newPerson)                   
                    // following works just fine except after ReceiveDisconnected call, the array has not been changed so there are two extra added to UI
                    setPeople(() => new PersonList(sd));  
                });

                connection.on('ReceiveDisconnected', id => {
                    const pd = people.Remove(id)  //removes the person with id          
                    setPeople(() => new PersonList(pd)); // after the line, UI updated to show 1 less person
                });
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('Connection failed: ', e));
    }
}, [connection]);
```

So I add 1 person and the UI updates to show that person. I add a second person and the state is updated and UI updates.

When a user disconnects, ReceiveDisconnected is called and the UI updates to shows only 1 person (as expected) seemingly indicating that people state has been updated.

But when a new user then connects, the state still has 2 items and the new person is added so the UI then shows the original 2 people + the third one.

Here is the issue diagrammatically

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+
|     action        |            UI         |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
| user1 connects    |       Person 1        | correct
+-------------------+-----------------------+
| user2 connects    |       Person 1        | correct
|                   |       Person 2        |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
| user2 disconnects |       Person 1        | correct
+-------------------+-----------------------+
| user3 connects    |       Person 1        | incorrect
|                   |       Person 2        |
|                   |       Person 3        |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

I've tried to add a setTimeout to the SetPeople call in ConnectToRoom to see if that helped as a debug but it makes no difference.

** UPDATE **

For the avoidance of doubt PersonList is a class which has an internal array of models:

```
  import defaultsDeep from "lodash/defaultsDeep";
  // https://opensource.com/article/20/5/data-modeling-javascript
  export class Model {
      constructor(attributes = {}) {
        defaultsDeep(this, attributes, this.defaults);
      }
  }

  export class List {
      constructor(items = []) {
        this.models = items.map(item => new this.model(item));
      }
  }

  export class PersonList extends List {
  get model() {
    return PersonModel;
  }



  findByFirstName(val) {
    return this.models.find(item => item.firstName === val);
  }

  Remove(id) {
    return this.models.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  }
}
```

For info, I have also tried the useRef trick in the oroginal question with thos class List and it works fine, so I am confident it is a stale state issue

Comment: `pd.push(newPerson)` Don't mutate state in React

Comment: I don't believe I am mutating state. I am mutating a copy of state and then using setPeople to set the updated state, That part of the code is working fine

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Recommend mocking your socket callbacks for the purpose of the example.

Comment: It sounds likely that `people` is stateful, so `people.models.push` will mutate that state.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Apologies, you are absolutely right. pd is just a reference to the stateful people. I have fixed that. Still not got it working, but a different issue now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

you're still using a state but not adding it to `useEffect` dependency or not using the `setState callback` :).

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (connection) {
    // ...
    connection.on("ConnectedToRoom", (id, name) => {
      const newPerson = new PersonModel({
        id: sid,
        firstName: name,
        present: true,
      });

      //const pd = people.models;
      //pd.push(newPerson);
      setPeople((peopleValue) => {
        // do whatever changes you need to make and then return the new state
        // I don't know what your state looks like but in most cases you can 
        // make a copy of the state, by simply destructuring it like this
        return [...peopleValue, newPerson];
      });
    });

    connection.on("ReceiveDisconnected", (id) => {
      setPeople((peopleValue) => {
        //again I don't know what people looks like 
        //but if it's an array which each item have a unique id you can do the following
        return peopleValue.filter(p => p.id !== id)
      });
    });
    //...
  }
}, [connection]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue is I am using a "List" class, rather than a simple array of PersonModel based on this: https://opensource.com/article/20/5/data-modeling-javascript Will try a regular array and see how that goes.